# Populating Drop down list from selection to another drop down value not show

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a trouble on how can I populate data to my third dropdown.
I have three dropdown, firstly when I click my first dropdown the second dropdown will populate list based on the value of my first dropdown and below my code it works fine.
The problem is, I want to populate list to my third dropdown when I click second dropdown but it didn't show anything.

```js
var mealsByCategory = 
    { A: [ 'San Francisco', 'Manila', 'Kirishima' ] 
    , B: [ 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb' ] 
    , C: [ 'c', 'ccc', 'cccc', 'ccccc', 'cccccc' ] 
    } 
var Mprovinces = 
    { A: [ 'San Francisco', 'Manila', 'Kirishima' ] 
    , B: [ 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb' ] 
    , C: [ 'c', 'ccc', 'cccc', 'ccccc', 'cccccc' ] 
    } 
    
function changemeal(value) {
  $('#category').prop('disabled', false);
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
}

function changecat(value) {
  $('#provinces').prop('disabled', false);
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("provinces").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions1 = "";
    for (categoryId in Mprovinces[value]) {
      catOptions1 += "<option>" + Mprovinces[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("provinces").innerHTML = catOptions1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onChange="changemeal(this.value);">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Province</option>
  <option value="A">Usa</option>
  <option value="B">Japan</option>
  <option value="C">China</option>
</select>

<select name="category" id="category" onChange="changecat(this.value);" disabled>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">Usa</option>
  <option value="B">Japan</option>
  <option value="C">China</option>
</select>

<select name="provinces" id="provinces" disabled>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it's because your data model is bad. you have to make it as a tree

Comment: @MisterJojo It does need to be a tree.  I've done various versions of this using nothing more than a single array.  Each item in the array is structured as something like `{"id":n, "displaytext":x, "parentid":n2}`  All top-level items have `"parentid":0` and all child items have the `id` value of the parent as their `parentid` value.  Then simple filtering will easily get the top-level items - they will all have 0 as the parentid, and child items can be found by filtering on parentid = id of parent.

Comment: @ATD can you provide solution? please. It almost 4 hours finding solution til now

Comment: I've added an Answer that shows you the sort of thing that I do.  It's not a full working version - but should be enough to give you an idea of what you can do and how

Comment: @ATD yes, your table structure is correct. It just lacks a way to indicate the hierarchical order of selects. I added my answer to show this.

Comment: And why does what it looks like matter?  If you wanted to, you could have separate arrays for parent, child and grandchild (to use your 3-levels as an example) and just filter the appropriate list.  Otherwise, you are creating custom objects to hold arrays within arrays just to make it look like a tree.  What is gained by doing that?

Comment: @ATD no, I'm talking about my `selOrder` array (to indicate the hierarchical order of selects) which can be  extended to "infinity" (doesn't exist in your code), without changing anything else in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a completely customisable way:

```js
let data = [{"id":1,"name":"USA","parentid":0},
{"id":2,"name":"Japan","parentid":0},
{"id":3,"name":"Europe","parentid":0},
{"id":4,"name":"California","parentid":1},
{"id":5,"name":"Oklahoma","parentid":1},
{"id":6,"name":"Arizona","parentid":1},
{"id":7,"name":"Kantô","parentid":2},
{"id":8,"name":"Kansai","parentid":2},
{"id":9,"name":"Chügoku","parentid":2},
{"id":10,"name":"France","parentid":3},
{"id":11,"name":"Deutschland","parentid":3},
{"id":12,"name":"Espana","parentid":3},
{"id":13,"name":"Sacramento","parentid":4},
{"id":14,"name":"Los Angeles","parentid":4},
{"id":15,"name":"San Diego","parentid":4},
{"id":16,"name":"Tulsa","parentid":5},
{"id":17,"name":"Oklahoma City","parentid":5},
{"id":18,"name":"Lawton","parentid":5},
{"id":19,"name":"Phoenix","parentid":6},
{"id":20,"name":"Flagstaff","parentid":6},
{"id":21,"name":"Tucson","parentid":6},
{"id":21,"name":"Tokyo","parentid":7},
{"id":22,"name":"Chiba","parentid":7},
{"id":23,"name":"Tochigi","parentid":7},
{"id":24,"name":"Kyoto","parentid":8},
{"id":25,"name":"Osaka","parentid":8},
{"id":26,"name":"Nara","parentid":8},
{"id":27,"name":"Tottori","parentid":9},
{"id":28,"name":"Hirochima","parentid":9},
{"id":29,"name":"Okayama","parentid":9},
{"id":30,"name":"Quimper","parentid":10},
{"id":31,"name":"Toulouse","parentid":10},
{"id":32,"name":"Nancy","parentid":10},
{"id":33,"name":"Dusseldorf","parentid":11},
{"id":34,"name":"Leipzig","parentid":11},
{"id":35,"name":"Munchen","parentid":11},
{"id":36,"name":"Barcelona","parentid":12},
{"id":37,"name":"Sevilla","parentid":12},
{"id":38,"name":"Guernica","parentid":12}]

function populateList(list, pid) {
  let l = document.getElementById(list);
  l.innerHTML = "";
  let topItem = document.createElement("option");
  topItem.value = 0;
  topItem.text = "--Select--";
  l.appendChild(topItem); 
  let items = data.filter(item => item.parentid == pid);
  items.forEach(function(item){
    let newItem = document.createElement("option");
    newItem.value = item.id;
    newItem.text = item.name;
    l.appendChild(newItem);
  })
}

function updateList(selList, thisList) {
  if (thisList.value != 0) {
    populateList(selList, Number(thisList.value));
  } else {
    let s = document.getElementById(selList);
    s.value = 0;
    triggerEvent(s, "onchange");
    let sCopy = s.cloneNode(false);
    let p = s.parentNode;
    p.replaceChild(sCopy, s);
  }
}
function triggerEvent(e, trigger)
{
    if ((e[trigger] || false) && typeof e[trigger] == 'function')
    {
        e[trigger](e);
    }
}
 

function loadList1() {
  populateList("list1", 0);
}

window.onload = loadList1;
```

```css
select {width:150px;}
```

```html
Region: <select id="list1" onchange="updateList('list2', this);"></select>
Sub-region:<select id="list2" onchange="updateList('list3', this);"></select>>
Location:<select id="list3"></select>
```

As long as the data structure is the same - ie `{"id":n, "name":"xxx", "parentid":n}` then the only change is the text next to each of the lists - otherwise, the function just needs to be updated to use the key names provided.  And, as all we are doing is populating lists based on the same array, they can all use the same base function - `populateList`.  The initial load and the selection from a list start off differently, but end up doing the same thing - filling a list based on the filtered array.

```js
function getText() {
  let thisList = document.getElementById("list1");
  console.log(thisList.value);
  console.log(thisList[thisList.selectedIndex].text);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="getText();">Click</button>

<select id="list1">
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I know its a bit late but do you have any idea? how can I get the text value of this select option, currently when I used your code above the value Im been getting is the ID instead the value, I'm been using python django, hoping

Comment: I don't use either python or django, so don't know how either would get any values/text from an HTML element.  I've updated the above code to show how it is done in javascript, which may work for you, or give you a starting point for your own code.

Answer (score 1):

my way...

```js
const f_Geo = document.getElementById('geographia-form')
 , selOrder = [ 'region', 'land', 'city' ] // hierarchical order of selects
 , treeData =
    [ { id:  1, name: 'USA',           parentID:  0 }
    , { id:  2, name: 'Japan',         parentID:  0 }
    , { id:  3, name: 'Europe',        parentID:  0 }
    , { id:  4, name: 'California',    parentID:  1 }
    , { id:  5, name: 'Oklahoma',      parentID:  1 }
    , { id:  6, name: 'Arizona',       parentID:  1 }
    , { id:  7, name: 'Kantô',         parentID:  2 }
    , { id:  8, name: 'Kansai',        parentID:  2 }
    , { id:  9, name: 'Chügoku',       parentID:  2 }
    , { id: 10, name: 'France',        parentID:  3 }
    , { id: 11, name: 'Deutschland',   parentID:  3 }
    , { id: 12, name: 'Espana',        parentID:  3 }
    , { id: 13, name: 'Sacramento',    parentID:  4 }
    , { id: 14, name: 'Los Angeles',   parentID:  4 }
    , { id: 15, name: 'San Diego',     parentID:  4 }
    , { id: 16, name: 'Tulsa',         parentID:  5 }
    , { id: 17, name: 'Oklahoma City', parentID:  5 }
    , { id: 18, name: 'Lawton',        parentID:  5 }
    , { id: 19, name: 'Phoenix',       parentID:  6 }
    , { id: 20, name: 'Flagstaff',     parentID:  6 }
    , { id: 21, name: 'Tucson',        parentID:  6 }
    , { id: 21, name: 'Tokyo',         parentID:  7 }
    , { id: 22, name: 'Chiba',         parentID:  7 }
    , { id: 23, name: 'Tochigi',       parentID:  7 }
    , { id: 24, name: 'Kyoto',         parentID:  8 }
    , { id: 25, name: 'Osaka',         parentID:  8 }
    , { id: 26, name: 'Nara',          parentID:  8 }
    , { id: 27, name: 'Tottori',       parentID:  9 }
    , { id: 28, name: 'Hirochima',     parentID:  9 }
    , { id: 29, name: 'Okayama',       parentID:  9 }
    , { id: 30, name: 'Quimper',       parentID: 10 }
    , { id: 31, name: 'Toulouse',      parentID: 10 }
    , { id: 32, name: 'Nancy',         parentID: 10 }
    , { id: 33, name: 'Dusseldorf',    parentID: 11 }
    , { id: 34, name: 'Leipzig',       parentID: 11 }
    , { id: 35, name: 'Munchen',       parentID: 11 }
    , { id: 36, name: 'Barcelona',     parentID: 12 }
    , { id: 37, name: 'Sevilla',       parentID: 12 }
    , { id: 38, name: 'Guernica',      parentID: 12 }
    ]
  ;
f_Geo.onsubmit=e=>e.preventDefault()  // disable submit
  ;
f_Geo.onchange=e=>
  {
  //if (!e.target.matches('select')) return  
  setSubSelects(e.target.name)
  }
function setSelect(name,id)
  {
  f_Geo[name].innerHTML = '' // clear select
  treeData.filter(el=>el.parentID===id)
          .forEach(el=>{ f_Geo[name].add( new Option(el.name, el.id)) })
  }
function setSubSelects(selectName)
  {
  let idx = selOrder.findIndex(x=>x===selectName) +1
  if (idx < selOrder.length)
    {
    let sName = selOrder[idx]
    setSelect ( sName,  +f_Geo[selectName].value )
    setSubSelects(sName)
    }
  }

setSelect('region',0)
setSubSelects('region')
```

```html
<form action="" id="geographia-form">
  <select name="region"></select>
  <select name="land"></select>
  <select name="city"></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is a very rough-and-ready example that I've just put together to give you an idea on the data structure and the javascript:

```js
let data = [{"id":1, "displaytext":"England", "parentid": 0},
{"id":2, "displaytext":"Scotland", "parentid": 0},
{"id":3, "displaytext":"Wales", "parentid": 0},
{"id":4, "displaytext":"Northern Ireland", "parentid": 0},
{"id":5, "displaytext":"London", "parentid": 1},
{"id":6, "displaytext":"Birmingham", "parentid": 1},
{"id":7, "displaytext":"Manchester", "parentid": 1},
{"id":8, "displaytext":"Edinburgh", "parentid": 2},
{"id":9, "displaytext":"Glasgow", "parentid": 2},
{"id":10, "displaytext":"Dundee", "parentid": 2},
{"id":11, "displaytext":"Cardiff", "parentid": 3},
{"id":12, "displaytext":"Swansea", "parentid": 3},
{"id":13, "displaytext":"Belfast", "parentid": 4},
{"id":14, "displaytext":"Lisburn", "parentid": 4}]

function loadParents() {
  let oList = document.getElementById("parent");
  let parents = data.filter(item => item.parentid == 0);
  let topItem = document.createElement("option");
  topItem.value = 0;
  topItem.text = "--Select--";
  oList.appendChild(topItem);
  parents.forEach(function(parent) {
    let newItem = document.createElement("option");
    newItem.value = parent.id;
    newItem.text = parent.displaytext;
    oList.appendChild(newItem);
  
  })
}

function getChildren() {
  let oList = document.getElementById("parent");
  let cList = document.getElementById("child");
  cList.innerHTML = "";
  let oFilter = oList.value;
  if (oList.value != 0) {
    let children = data.filter(item => item.parentid == oFilter);
    let topItem = document.createElement("option");
      topItem.value = 0;
      topItem.text = "--Select--";
      cList.appendChild(topItem);
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      let newItem = document.createElement("option");
      newItem.value = child.id;
      newItem.text = child.displaytext;
      cList.appendChild(newItem);
    })
  }
}


window.onload = loadParents;
```

```html
<select id="parent" onchange="getChildren()";></select><select id="child"></select>
```

This is just a simple list of UK countries and some of their cities.  Select a country from the first list and the second list is replaced by the "children" of that "parent".