# One event handler for multiple selects

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have multiple selects on a page, like this:

```html
<select id="select-1" class="action">
  <option val=1>1</option>
  <option val=2>2</option>
</select>
<select id="select-2">
  <option val=1>1</option>
  <option val=2>2</option>
</select>
<select id="select-3" class="action">
  <option val=1>1</option>
  <option val=2>2</option>
</select>
```

I need to do some actions with JS code when selects with class "action" are changed.

I could do something like this:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

But maybe there is a better way to handle this.

So my question is: what is the best way to use one event handler to handle multiple select elements?

Comment: See here: https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of  all : your html is invalid : options element has value attribute , no val, and this value must have quotes around.

so  `<option val=1>1</option>` is wrong,
and must be `<option value="1">1</option>`

for event delegation, you need to have a parent element.

As  your code are about select elements, the logic parent should be a `<form>` element.

and for the selects, the main event is a change event, not a click event

last things, all form element must have a name, this name is used when the form is submited , and not the id.

the other interest to use name attribute in forms, is they can be directly used to reference any sub element of the form

so the complete code is:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

// get any -change- event on all the form
myForm.addEventListener('change', myFunction, false) 

// event delegation function
function myFunction(evt)
  {
   // ignore other cases:
  if (!evt.target.matches('select.action')) return

  console.clear()
  console.log( 'change on :', evt.target.name )
  console.log( 'value is', myForm[evt.target.name].value )
  }
  
// disable form submit
myForm.onsubmit =evt=>evt.preventDefault()
```

```html
<form action="" name="my-form">
  <select name="select-1" class="action">
    <option value="s1_1"> s1 -1 </option>
    <option value="s1_2"> s1 -2 </option>
  </select>
  <select name="select-2">
    <option value="s2_11"> s2 -1 </option>
    <option value="s2_12"> s2 -2 </option>
  </select>
  <select name="select-3" class="action">
    <option value="s3_11"> s3 -1 </option>
    <option value="s3_12"> s3 -2 </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it a good solution to fire change event for every change on a form? Looks slightly redundant, is it ok for JS?

Comment: @Gleb it all depends on what you want to obtain, the principle of the event delegation is a tool among so many others, each to its use.
I recently posted here a demo on a cascading select system, the event delegation allows you to have an unlimited number of selects, you should watch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195403/populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-to-another-drop-down-value-not-show/64197126#64197126

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use [*event delegation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation), where you hook `click` on an ancestor element that all of these selects are in, and take advantage of the fact that `click` *bubbles*:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const select = event.target.closest(".action");
    if (select && this.contains(select)) {
        event.currentTarget = select;
        return myFunction.call(select, event);
    }
});
```

The update of `currentTarget` and calling `myFunction` with `this` set to the `select` make it look like the event was directly attached to the select. You **don't** have to do that, though, or you could do just one but not the other, it depends on what you want `myFunction` to do.

See on MDN:

- [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`Node#contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)