# Local Storage set to dropdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm been using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204274/14385814). The issue is when I'm done submitting and filling those dropdown it reloads, When I come back again the previous value will gone. I just want to remain those value in dropdown but I think there is a conflict when using that link above. It also didn't display the other value of dropdown. All I know I should use localStorage. Is there any expert can give me directions and ideas for this?

[image]

> Setting the value of dropdown when I click search/submit button

```
var values = document.getElementById('province').value;
localStorage.setItem("prov", values);
```

> getting the value of province dropdown

```
 document.getElementById("province").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("prov");
```

> It is possible to apply this through that link I provided?

Comment: You got the `value`, so set the `value`, not `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make an object that you can read from with mental ease.. something like

```
var obj={province:provinceElement.value, municipality:Municipality.value, ...etc}
```

then when you save all your values to the object, save it with a key("whatever it is once it's a key only your code uses")

```
localStorage.setItem("uniqueKeyOnlyMyCodeUses",JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Then you can get all your data like

```
var localObj=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("uniqueKeyOnlyMyCodeUses"))
```

`localObj` would have all the data you saved in just one key and objects are a very easy way to play around with the data you gave

Comment: Thanks for your response what does `provinceElement.value` mean it is the ID of the dropdown?

Comment: `provenceElement` is `document.getElementById('province')` as in the raw domElement itself @HannahMae